# Dynamically fixing some variables when using fmincon

Tags: matlab, optimization, dynamic, constraints, minimization

I have a MINLP objective function and I want to fix some variables value into constant as an example described below:

```
A = [1 1 1];
b = 30;
x1 = zeros(1,3);
y=1;
x = fmincon(@(x)objfun(x,y),x1,A,b);

function f = objfun(x,y)
x(y) = 1;
f = x(1)^2 + x(2)^2 + x(3)^2;
end
```

However, the result of variable `x` is all zeros. It seems that `x(1)` cannot be forced to be `1`. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a different syntax of `fmincon`:

```
fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
```

Then, if you wish to only limit one of the values, you can use these bounds:

```
lb = [1 -Inf -Inf]; 
ub = [1 Inf Inf];
```

Since you will also need to specify the inputs `Aeq` and `beq`, don't forget you can use `[]` for any inputs you don't want/need to specify, as shown in [this example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#busow0w-1) in the documentation:

```
fun = @(x)1+x(1)./(1+x(2)) - 3*x(1).*x(2) + x(2).*(1+x(1));
lb = [0,0];
ub = [1,2];
A = [];
b = [];
Aeq = [];
beq = [];
x0 = [0.5,1];
[x,fval] = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
```